# How to set SQL Always On in ConnectionInfo of Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

My company has plan to enable the SQL Always On, the DB Connection String has new parameter "MultiSubnetFailover=True".

SDK info: **CrystalDecisions.Shared** (version **13.0.2000.0**)

Is there any way to set new parameter "MultiSubnetFailover=True"?

```
ConnectionInfo objConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo
{
    ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerName"],
    DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDatabaseName"],
    UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDatabaseUser"],
    Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportDatabasePassword"],
};
TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connection;
table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
```

I tried to add the attritube in DbConnectionAttributes. But i got the error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Failed to load database information."

````
         var attribute = new DbConnectionAttributes();
         attribute.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("MultiSubnetFailover", "True"));
                     objConnectionInfo.Attributes = attribute;```
````